# How to deal with the force of the form $\delta (\mathbf{r}) u(\mathbf{r})$, $u(\mathbf{r})$is the interaction potential

Tags: forces, dirac-delta-distributions, molecular-dynamics

Now I have such an expression for potential energy:
$$
U_j(\mathbf{r}_j) = \int_{\mathbf{r}_j-\frac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2}}^{\mathbf{r}_j+\frac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2}} d\mathbf{r} \sum_{\mathbf{n}} \sum_{i\ne j}^{N} \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i + \mathbf{n} \mathbf{L}^B) u_{j}^b(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_j)
$$
$\mathbf{r}_j(x_j,y_j,z_j), \mathbf{L}^b(L_x^b,L_y^b,L_z^b), \mathbf{n}(n_x,n_y,n_z), \mathbf{L}^B(L_x^B,L_y^B,L_z^B)$ are all three dimensional vectors. $n_x,n_y,n_z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Also, $\mathbf{n L}^b = (n_x L_x^b,n_y L_y^b,n_z L_z^b)$. Note $\mathbf{L}^b \ne \mathbf{L}^B $, this is the heart of the problem. Find the expression for the force on this potential energy：
$$
\begin{align}
-F_j(\mathbf{r}_j) =& \dfrac{d U_j(\mathbf{r}_j)}{d\mathbf{r}_j} \notag \\
     =&\sum_{\mathbf{n}}\sum_{i\ne j} \delta(\mathbf{r}_j + \dfrac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2} - \mathbf{r}_i + \mathbf{n}\mathbf{L}^B ) u_j^b(\dfrac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2}) \notag \\
     & - \sum_{\mathbf{n}}\sum_{i\ne j} \delta(\mathbf{r}_j - \dfrac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2} - \mathbf{r}_i + \mathbf{n} \mathbf{L}^B ) u_j^b(-\dfrac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2}) \notag \\
     +&\int_{\mathbf{r}_j-\frac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2}}^{\mathbf{r}_j+\frac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2}} d\mathbf{r} \sum_{\mathbf{n}} \sum_{i\ne j }^{N} \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i + \mathbf{n} \mathbf{L}^B) \dfrac{d u_{j}^b(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_j)}{d\mathbf{r}_j} \notag
\end{align}
$$
where $u_j^b(\mathbf{r}) $is a two-body interaction potential and its mathematical form is known.
But I don't know how to deal with The first term on the right-hand side of the equation. How to convert the term containing $\delta(\mathbf{r})$ into a form that can be directly calculated

Comment: Your notation doesn't make sense. You cannot directly differentiate the potential $U(\mathbf{r})$ w.r.t. a vector like d$\mathbf{r}$.

Comment: @Yejus While there are problems in the notations, I don't think this is one of them. $\partial U/\partial\vec{r}$ is a common notation for the gradient.

Comment: @Yejus This is another way of writing the gradient of potential energy without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the notation being used here. An integral of the form $\int_{0}^a dx~\delta(x) f(x)$ isn't well-defined since the lower integration limit exactly coincides with the place the delta function blows up (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1808496/437059) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/347520/437059) for a discussion of this). Also, I'm not sure what you mean by $\int_0^\mathbf{r+b} d\mathbf{a}~(\cdot)$. It's written similar to a 1D integral but the notation seems to hint that all quantities are vectors.

With these two issues in mind, my best guess is that this is what you have in mind. Let $\mathbf{r},\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Then
\begin{align}
U(\mathbf{r})  &= \int_{0^-}^{r_1+b_d}da_1 ... \int_{0^-}^{r_d+b_d}da_d~\delta(\mathbf{a})u(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{r}),
\end{align}
where the notation $\int_{0^-}^a dx~(\cdot)$ stands for $\lim_{\epsilon\nearrow 0}\int_{\epsilon}^a dx~(\cdot)$.
In that case, you can first simplify $U(\mathbf{r})$:
\begin{align}
U(\mathbf{r})  &= u(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{r}) = u(\mathbf{b}),
\end{align}
meaning that the force $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}U(\mathbf{r}) = 0$ if $\mathbf{b}$ is independent of $\mathbf{r}$.

**Response to New Edits**

Again, first evaluate the integral in $U_j(\mathbf{r}_j)$ before trying to calculate the gradient.
\begin{align}
U_j(\mathbf{r}_j) &= \sum_{\mathbf{n}} \sum_{i\neq j}\int_{x_j - L_x^b/2}^{x_j + L_x^b/2} dx \int_{y_j - L_y^b/2}^{y_j + L_y^b/2} dy\int_{z_j - L_z^b/2}^{z_j + L_z^b/2} dz ~ \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i+\mathbf{n}\mathbf{L}^B) u_j^b(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_j)\\[5pt]
&= \sum_{\mathbf{n}} \sum_{i\neq j} u_j^b(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{n}\mathbf{L}^B)\times \mathcal{I}(\mathbf{r}_i,\mathbf{r}_j,\mathbf{n}),
\end{align}
where I've defined the function
$$\mathcal{I}(\mathbf{r}_i,\mathbf{r}_j,\mathbf{n}) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j \in\text{cuboid centered at }\mathbf{n}\mathbf{L}^B\text{ with side lengths }\mathbf{L}^b\\[5pt]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
You can now proceed with calculating the gradient. I'll leave that calculation to you. As a hint, handling the $\mathcal{I}$ function is straightforward since it's zero in one region and one in the other. So just consider each case separately.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed the lower bound to 0 to simplify the problem. The actual problem is this, the upper and lower bounds of the integral have variables. How should this be handled please

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang Please first clarify what you mean by the notation $\int_\mathbf{a}^\mathbf{b} d\mathbf{r}~(\cdot)$. Is it a volume integration like I assumed or is it some kind of contour integration?

Comment: This integral is a volume integral with $\mathbf{r}_j$ as the body center of the cuboid and $\mathbf{L}^b$ as the side length

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: $$\int_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}} d \amthbf{r} (\codt) = \int_{a_x}^{b_x) dx \int_{a_y}^{b_y} dy \int_{a_z}^{b_z} dz (\cdot) $$

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang There's still something wrong with your notation. Inside the delta function you have $\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i + \mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{L}^b$. You're adding a vector ($\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i $) to a scalar ($\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{L}^b$), which is ill-defined.

Comment: Yes, what I want to express here is $\mathbf{n}  \mathbf{L}^B = (n_xL_x^B, n_yL_y^B,n_zL_z^B$, I have corrected it

Comment: I'm very sorry for the ambiguity caused by my negligence

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang No worries. See my edited answer. For next time, try to really think about what each of the terms in your equations mean. Proper notation isn't just for your audience, it's also good for your own understanding.

Comment: thanks for your advice. But there is a problem $ \mathbf{L}^b \ne  \mathbf{L}^B  $, This is the core of my question, if the two are equal I've got the answer. even $\mathbf{L}^b = \mathbf{n} \mathbf{L}^B $ i got the answer. But when this condition is not met and $\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_i =  \pm \dfrac{ \mathbf{L}^b }{2}$ will appear $\delta(0) u_j^b (\dfrac{\mathbf{L}^b}{2})$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137208/discussion-between-sahand-tabatabaei-and-zhao-dazhuang).